# regex that matches 2 types of url

Tags: regex

I would like to have a regex that matches both of the following examples:

```
http://testsite.com/1234/MyPage
http://testsite.com/MyPage
```

The following examples should however not match:

```
http://testsite.com/
http://testsite.com/anything/MyPage
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^http:\/\/testsite\.com(?:\/1234)?\/MyPage$
```

And here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/eu6HdA/4

---

If you want to have a list of allowed subpages, you can use the following regular expression:

```
^http:\/\/testsite\.com(?:\/(?:1234|4567|7890))?\/MyPage$
```

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/eu6HdA/5

---

**Explanation:**

- `^` start of the string
- `http:\/\/testsite\.com` escaping with `\` is necessary for special regex characters
- `(?:\/1234)?` match an **optional** non-matching group of `/1234`
- `(?:\/(?:1234|4567|7890))?` match an **optional** non-matching group with `/` and the one of the following `1234`, `4567` or `7890`
- `$` end of the string